# How to set ScanFilter on android app

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm building an app that should to connect a BLE Device.

So I want to set a filter when I scan the BLE device available.

I know what is my BLE Address

```
9C:20:7B:CB:A6:22
```

So, I try to creare a ScanFilter with this code:

```
ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(
                    ParcelUuid.fromString("9C:20:7B:CB:A6:22")).build();
```

but if I try to start my applicaton, I have this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eresult.diabesitycare.devicesensor/com.eresult.diabesitycare.devicesensor.BLEActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID: 9C:20:7B:CB:A6:22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLE Address `9C:20:7B:CB:A6:22` isn't identical to UUID. According to [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#terms):

> Attribute Protocol (ATT)—GATT is built on top of the Attribute Protocol (ATT). This is also referred to as GATT/ATT. ATT is optimized to run on BLE devices. To this end, it uses as few bytes as possible. Each attribute is uniquely identified by a Universally Unique Identifier (UUID), which is a standardized 128-bit format for a string ID used to uniquely identify information. The attributes transported by ATT are formatted as characteristics and services.

So your uuid should be **standardized 128-bit format for a string ID**, like `0000110B-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`.

Look [Reading BLE Attributes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#read) to read your device UUID first.

Answer (score 0):

Android allows for MAC address filtering during a Bluetooth Low Energy scan.

Create a list of ScanFilter objects, each one holding a desired MAC address:

```java
String macAddress = "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF";
List<ScanFilter> scanFilterList = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>(Arrays.asList(new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(macAddress).build()));
```

Then you can pass these into the adapter's `startScan` method:

```java
BluetoothLeScanner leScanner;
leScanner.startScan(scanFilterList, scanSettings, callbackFunc);
```

[Link to guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-ble-devices)